# Performance Issues when querying FROM Hbase using Spark TO Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I have a huge nearly billion of rows in the HBase database.  I am writing a Spark job that pulls data from Hbase efficiently based on date range and push that data to elastic search for indexing in batches.  I am using  hbase-spark connector with JavaHBaseContext spark SQL with dataframe to get the data.  Later I to push this data for indexing in batches to elasticsearch.

I am having performance issues first with getting data from Hbase then indexing and pushing data to elasticsearch.  Please let me know how should I efficiently perform above operation.

P.S:Hbase is backed by data in S3

Comment: Please provide some relevant code. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from HBase?  What kind of filter are you using based on date range? can you show this please